# Copy file to new location

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, fs, discord.js

I'm trying to copy a file with the data inside a new file in a folder.
I tried doing this but it didn't work:

```
copyFile(`./data/guilddata/guilds/default/GUILDID.json`, `./data/guilddata/guilds/${guild.id}/GUILDID.json`, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-copy-file

Does anyone know what to do? (`${guild.id}` just means the guild id, the folder is already there). I also get no errors. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.copyFile('./data/guilddata/guilds/default/GUILDID.json', './data/guilddata/guilds/' + guild.id + '/GUILDID.json', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('All done! The file is copied!');
});
```